# MacBook Pro 13' Power cord

Tags: charging, power

I use a 6 outlet adapter on my wall outlet. Since it's on the wall, it gets loose sometimes. This morning I pushed it in, while my power cord was plugged into it and the the power cord was plugged into my computer. There was a 'short' where I blew a fuse, and it sparked. I immediately unplugged my computer. My computer is working fine, but I'm afraid to use the power cord now. Is it still good? Can I hurt my computer?

Comment: This is likely a question you should be asking to a licensed electrician and not a forum regarding Apple products. My greater concern would be the risk of an electrical fire that the short may have caused and this should be checked as soon as possible by an electrician.

Answer (score 1):

If the computer's working fine, then the electrical event that occurred either didn't damage the computer, or only damaged the charging circuitry.

I wouldn't try using the adapter again. If you do, there's a high likelihood that it will trip another circuit breaker/blow a fuse, or it may not do anything at all. I think it's very unlikely in either case that it will charge your computer again.

If the adapter is an Apple adapter, take it back to an Apple Store, they'll most likely replace it on the spot. If it's an aftermarket adapter, get an Apple adapter, I've never had an Apple one malfunction.

I'm not a licensed electrician, but I do know my way around electricity/electrics. I **strongly** recommend you discard the charger if it's an aftermarket adapter, or have it replaced if it's an Apple one.